# Powershell - Disable expired users

Tags: powershell

I need to run a command that disables users who have an account expiration date 7 days BEFORE the current date.

At the moment I have only been able to find code that looks at users who are expiring in the future

```
 Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan "7"
```

or have simply already expired (can't specify date)

Comment: You could try a "-7" or manually building in passing in a DateTime object ala `DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7)` but I don't know if the Expired vs Expiring designation is going to make this impossible for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$date = (Get-Date) - (New-TimeSpan -Days 7)
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring | ? { $_.AccountExpirationDate -le $date }
```

It'll return any accounts where the expiration date is less than the date seven days ago.

Comment: Doesn't return anything for me. The Date side of things works however it doesn't seem to be searching AD, is it something to do with the format of the date that's given from the first line?

Comment: Does it work with -AccountExpired instead of -AccountExpiring?

Comment: It didn't. I don't get any errors, just no results at all.